# Installing a 3rd-party libraries to use in my C program

Tags: c, makefile, build

I'm very new to `C` programming and I'm trying to understand what is the "idiomatic way" to install a 3rd-part library that I'm planning to use in my project.

In the JVM world I came from we have a public repositories and a build system does all the dependency downloading for us. Is it the way to go when it comes to developing native application in `C`?

In my particular case it is `libcurl` and I want to make sure it is installed correctly. As a build system I use `Make` (not `CMake`).

Would it be correct to add a specific target (e.g. `bootstrap` which is to setup all the necessary dependencies) for that?

I'm strictly speaking not sure if such a "dependencies-installation" is a `Makefile` responsibility.

Comment: A third party library could be provided as source code you compile with your application, as a static library, or as a dynamic library.  How you would work with it depends which type of library you use.  As for checking dependencies, something like the autotools autoconfig can check things in the environment

Answer (score 2):

When you build on Linux using the autotools it will check if the given library is present on the System. If it is missing the configure will stop and notice the user. The user then has the Chance to install the Software library with the system's repository.

Same with cmake where you can define the dependency and when trying to build with the missing library, cmake will notify you.

This is somewhat different than e.g. Maven in the Java world which automatically downloads the dependencies. This is not the case with make or cmake.

Answer (score 1):

If you are under the Linux that this might be helpful. There is a canonical way. This is “autotools”. It provides you with possibility to write some script to check that library exists and then use it. I’m not much familiar with this process, but it’s pretty configurable and you can find dozens of examples and tutorials regarding “autotools”. So, if this is a case of yours, I suggest you to check that.

In my experience, I always used CMake.